# Can't show more than one geolocations using google map api in one page

Tags: javascript, html, image, google-maps-api-3

I use [googleapi](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) to show [geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) of multiple places in one page but it's not possible.

I initialize a variable to count the maps:

```
var countmaps=1;
```

I do the following in a loop(for each map i want to show):

First of all i get longitude and latitude from an xml file. This is working:

```
var lat= latitude[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
var lon= longitude[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

After this i create a new paragraph element for holding each map:

```
var newmap=document.createElement('p');
```

Id of the element is map1 for the first map, map2 for the second etc.

```
newmap.id="maps" + countmaps;
```

Then, i save the id in a variable:

```
var getid= "maps" + countmaps;
```

I append the new element to a div called section:

```
section.appendChild(newmap);
```

So far everything is working fine.
Then i define the functions for showing the map. I took them from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp):

```
    function getLocation()
      {
            if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
        }
      else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";//not important
      }
      }

    function showPosition()
      {
      var latlon=lat+","+lon;

      var img_url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
      +latlon+"&zoom=14&size=400x300&sensor=false";
    //i get element with id map1 in the first loop, map2 in the second etc in the below
      document.getElementById(getid).innerHTML="<img src='"+img_url+"'>";
      }

    function showError(error)
      {
      switch(error.code) 
        {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
          document.getElementById(getid).innerHTML="MAP Not Available"
          break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
         document.getElementById(getid).innerHTML="MAP Not Available"
          break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
          document.getElementById(getid).innerHTML="MAP Not Available"
          break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
          document.getElementById(getid).innerHTML="MAP Not Available"
          break;
        }


 }
```

Finally, i call getlocation function and increase the counter for my element ids.

```
getLocation();
 countmaps++;
```

In most of the cases i only got the last map.
Can you explain this behavior?

Comment: Why do you need to run the geolocation more than once?  It is going to return the same location each time.

Comment: im getting a different longitude and latitude from an xml file each time

Comment: I am asking about the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`/ the [geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp).  Do you really get a different position from that each time?

Comment: yes, you are right, that was my mistake :) you can insert that as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call the geolocation service multiple times, each will return the same result.